# New column based on other columns

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have two columns (V1 and V2) with character information. I want to create a third column with the "sum" of this characters. Like unique values between comma's "," inside the character vectors on both columns (V1 and V2).

I want to go from this:

Example data:

```
data.frame(V1 = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','','C'),
           V2 = c('A, B','A','B','','A, C','A, B','A',''))


  V1   V2
1  A    A, B
2  A    A
3  A    B
4  A     
5  B    A, C
6  B    A, B
7       A
8  C
```

To this:

```
   V3
1   AB
2   A
3   AB
4   A
5   ABC
6   AB
7   A
8   C
```

Comment: You want to sort them as well? Row five should result in `ABC` and not `BAC`?

Comment: This doesn't really matter, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse way using `purrr` and `dplyr`. You can probably condense this into fewer lines, but this is readable enough.

1. Split the text on the comma.
2. Sort and combine the two columns.
3. Paste them back together.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  modify(str_split, ",\\s") %>% 
  mutate(V3 = map2(V1, V2, compose(sort, unique, c))) %>%
  mutate(V3 = map_chr(V3, paste, collapse = ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the column 'V2', get the `union` of both columns and `paste`

```
data.frame(V3 = mapply(\(x, y) paste(sort(union(x, y)), 
  collapse = ""), strsplit(df1$V2, ",\\s*"), df1$V1))
```

-output

```
   V3
1  AB
2   A
3  AB
4   A
5 ABC
6  AB
7   A
8   C
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach first `paste` `V1` and `V2` together, then use `strsplit` to split the string, then only keep the `unique` characters and collapse them together.

```
df$V3 <- sapply(strsplit(gsub(",\\s", "", paste0(df$V1, df$V2)), ""), 
                             function(x) paste0(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ""))

   V3
1  AB
2   A
3  AB
4   A
5 ABC
6  AB
7   A
8   C
```

Answer (score 2):

With regex:

```
gsub("(.)(?=.*\\1)|,| ", "", paste(df$V1, df$V2), perl = TRUE)

# [1] "AB"  "A"   "AB"  "A"   "BAC" "AB"  "A"   "C"
```